# How to count with jquery number of elements on remote page?

Tags: jquery

I would like to count number of elements on remote page:
For example remote page:

test.html with following structure

```
<div id="Layout">
   <div class="product">...</div>
   <div class="product">...</div>
   <div class="product">...</div>
</div>
```

Then I would like call from test2.html

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#result').load('/test.html #Layout product').length();
        });
    </script>
```

This code is not working. What is the right way to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the elements are actually loaded, you can use the callback function argument of the [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result').load('/test.html #Layout', function () {
    var products = $('.product', this).length;
    alert(products);
  });
});
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/ituko4).

Also, if you don't want to insert the loaded elements into the DOM, you can load them into a new empty element, for example:

```
$('<div></div>').load('/test.html #Layout', function () {
  var products = $('.product', this).length;
  alert(products);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is is possible not load content of test.html to #result. #result should display only total number of elements from remote page. Thank you again.

Comment: @mp1, you're welcome, for doing that, take my second example and replace `alert(products);` for `$('#result').text(products);`